# how to enable Access-Control-Allow-Headers in xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

An `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` error arises when using HTML with Jquery to call an API:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.xxxx.com/col?system=xxx&keyid=xxxxx&rtype=city&region=" + citiCd);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    var datax = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
    //my stuff
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

When run, it produces this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.xxxx.com/col?system=xxx&keyid=xxxxx&rtype=city&region=DLI.
>   Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How do I enable access? I tried `xdomainrequest` without luck.

Answer (score -1):

I've faced that issue a few times and it should be resolved on the server side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: i added these in my code
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

but still getting same error. Asterisks are there in between single quote .

Comment: server side means where api is hosted or where my page is hosted??

Comment: server side means as in API

Comment: thanks icyKira. can you a bit specify what should I do on server side so that i can get data.

Comment: What is being used on the API side NodeJS, ASP.NET Web API or?

Comment: its 3rd party api, I asked him but reply will take some time , but it is hosted in app.apiary.io platform.